# cancel load page in javascript

Tags: javascript

I define a link <a href="http://www.example.com">Hello</a>.when i click this link javascript should check the link is exist/valid.if true,the page should be load or the page should resirect to another page.i am using javascript ajax to check the page exist/not.i am using the condition xmlhttp.status == 200.But it is not working.here is the code:

```
function check(url){
    xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){

        if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
            if (xmlHttp.status==200) 
            {
                alert("Page  Available");
            }
            else 
            {
                window.location.href= "http://www.hello.com";
            }
        }
    }

    xmlHttp.send(null);
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<a href="http://www.example.com" onclick="check(this)">Click this Link</a>
```

here xmlHttp.status==200 is not working.can anyone help me?

Comment: Define "not working".  It's an equality operator, I strongly suspect it's working correctly.  Do you mean that the status isn't 200 when you expect it to be?  Or that the comparison is never called?  Or that there really is some problem with your JS engine's implementation?

Comment: You can't make a cross domain request on the client-side. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466737/why-is-cross-domain-ajax-a-security-concern

Comment: On a completely different note, if you're only interested in the status code of the request, you should make a `HEAD` request instead of a `GET`.  Much lighter weight (i.e. quicker and cheaper and "better") and contains all the information you need.

Comment: i tried head and it is not a problem of JS Engine.becaus i tried in different systems.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, multiple points:

1. `onclick="check(this)"` doesn't pass the URL to the `check` function but a reference to the the link object. So if you want to pass the URL, you have to reference the `href` attribute.
2. You shouldn't set `window.location.href` when you want to output something else *afterwards*. Setting the current location *can* make the browser change the page directly, so the `alert` probably won't change.
3. Why the `if` where you change the location to google each time?
4. You can *only* abort the processing of link click, by returning `false` in the event handler.
5. AJAX calls are, as the first parameter says, *asynchronous*. But as you abort the page loading already (by clicking on the link), the AJAX call gets aborted.
6. You can't return `false` from inside of the AJAX event handler (`onreadystatechange`) to stop the processing of the link. By the time you get there, the link is already processed.
7. That, what you are trying, is not really good. It should be up to the user to check if a page exists or not. It would be very wrong to redirect him to some other page (here: google) just because the link didn't work; at least I would be very confused. Also by checking that with AJAX, you make the user load the page twice, which is bad as well.

Comment: onclick="check(this)".it passes the url

Comment: @anish: No, it passes a reference to the DOM element. It just equals to the URL when casted as string. Check with `typeof( url )` in the `check` function.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers won't allow you to make a *cross domain* request.

See more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466737/why-is-cross-domain-ajax-a-security-concern), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558977/ajax-cross-domain-call) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ajax+cross+domain).

Answer (score 0):

1. Has to be from the same domain or the domain has to use CORS for safari 4 and Fx 3.5+
2. you need to return false on the click
3. you need to use the url.href
4. you need to alert before you redirect

`function check(link){`
`/* ONLY works from same domain OR if the target implemented CORS! */`

```
    xmlHttp.open("GET", link.href, true);  

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){

    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
        if (xmlHttp.status==200) 
        {
            alert("Page  Available");
        }
        else 
        {
            window.location.href= "http://www.hello.com";
        }
    }
}

xmlHttp.send(null);
return false; // imperative
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<a href="http://www.example.com" onclick="return check(this)">Click this Link</a>
```

Comment: Finally got something posted that looks like code. SO was NOT happy and I indented and indented

Answer (score 0):

Your onclick attribute should contain:

```
 check(this.href);
```

Comment: but i get the url in a funtion.i checked with an alert

Comment: You saw the URL printed, but that's because the `a` element's `toString()` method returns the URL, not because it *is* the URL

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the url. You are passing the DOM element of the link. You need to use url.href or in jQuery you need to use $(this).attr('href').

Also the JavaScript is not preventing the link from being followed. You need to have the function return false, and have no errors before it does or you can use jQuery and event.preventDefault().

Finally even if you did all because of the same origin policy it will only work for links on the same domain you're on. [Here is a link to a jQuery version of your code.](http://jsfiddle.net/adamzr/guypy/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok you are nearly there. A lot of useful comments so far. But it might be better to redirect from the server not from the client.
I personally would pass parameter to a function on your server (your server script's url) (capturing the href using jQuery) to a function on your server, then use that passed url to do a (head) check and redirect them via the server if it exists.
If the site doesn't exist, then don't redirect and just send JSON back to the client and let them know the site doesn't exist.