# Cross-domain bypass?

Tags: javascript, json

I am currently trying to obtain this JSON array from

http://d.yimg.com/aq/autoc?query=goo&region=US&lang=en-US

However, which ever I use, it does not seem to work.

Using

```
$.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: 'http://d.yimg.com/aq/autoc?query=goo&region=US&lang=en-US',
       cache : false,
       dataType : 'json',
       success: function(data){
       alert('got it!');
       }

}
```

And also tried

```
$.getJSON("http://d.yimg.com/aq/autoc?query=goo&region=US&lang=en-US, function(data) {
        });
```

As well as looking into a bypass for cross domain, and I tried using a proxy, not did not work, Maybe I am implementing it wrong? I can not seem to properly obtain the data (nothing return to data).

**EDITED**

I used this bypass php proxy to try and bypass the missing CORS and JSONP, and it does not seem to return the data correctly either (I followed an example). The php is within my directory.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tickBox").on("input", function(e) {
        'use strict';
        var tick = document.getElementById("tickBox").value;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://d.yimg.com/aq/autoc?query=goo&region=US&lang=en-US',
            crossOrigin : true,
            //dataType : 'json',
            context: {},
            success: function(data){
                alert(data.ResultSet.Result[0].name);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you try `crossDomain:true` in your `ajax` opts?

Comment: Sorry, the originally `?format=json` is not usually there, I thought I could possibly format the URL, but even without it, it does not work

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna I tried the `crossDomain`, it did not work unfortunately, I used my `alert` as a debug, it did not pop up.

Comment: The API you're trying to get data from needs to support cross origin resources sharing (CORS) or JSONP. If it doesn't, there is no way to access it using Ajax from a browser.

Comment: https://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/json.html#callbackparam

Comment: @BaoThai you can try using the lib : http://www.ajax-cross-origin.com/ . remember for security reason it's not a good practice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery AJAX cross domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain)

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna Ahhhh wonderful! Hmmm, I guess I would have to use this solution temporarily. What would you say is a safer solution? Also, I am trying to access the data returned. It did returned, but data access is rather weird.

Comment: I'm receiving this: `"{"ResultSet":{"Query":"goo","Result":[{"symbol":"GOOG","name":"Alphabet (...) {"symbol":"BGFV","name":"Big 5 Sporting Goods Corporation","exch":"NMS","type":"S","exchDisp":"NASDAQ","typeDisp":"Equity"}]}}`, but then I'm using IE10, so...

Comment: @BekimBacaj I am too, but is the way I am trying to access the data is invalid?

Comment: Does coding matter if I am using chrome? @BekimBacaj

Comment: @BaoThai read the accepted answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466737/why-the-cross-domain-ajax-is-a-security-concern

Comment: @BekimBacaj My apologies, I meant I am also getting that JSON string.

Comment: @BaoThai that's what you've requested - that's what you and everybody else will get.

Comment: @BekimBacaj Ah alright, thank you.

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna hahaha, sorry. Seems like a problem has arise... The cross-domain worked with this google api I had for that last couple days, suddenly it is not working anymore. Not sure, but can't seem to find if anyone has/had the same problem as me.